# Power User SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

We define as power users those users who bought at least 10 products. How to write a query that returns for each user on which day they became a power user. That is, for each user, on which day they bought the 10th item.

The table below represents transactions. That is, each row means that the corresponding user has bought something on that date.

Userid means the id of the user
Date means one particular user bought something on 2017-09-01 10:23:03

```
| Userid    | Date                | 
-----------------------------------
| 123445678 | 2017-09-01 10:23:03 |
| 876543215 | 2016-08-31 08:12:23 |
| 324567893 | 2012-03-02 07:23:12 | 
| 234545566 | 2011-03-04 05:22:13 |
| 783465863 | 2009-03-05 12:23:23 |
```

Comment: you should be start by sharing the tables and example data as ascii text tables.. we can't give you a query without knowing the structure/data

Comment: Thank you example data added

Comment: Is that the table containing user's transactions? What's the name of the table. If there is any important associated table you left out, could you add it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer can avoid string manipulation

```
select user_id,date
from (select *,row_number() over(partition by user_id order by date) as row_num
from poweruser
) tmp
where row_num=10;
```

Comment: Nice utilization of partition / where

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by grouping the data per user and then getting the date of the 10th transaction for all the users.

```
SELECT `UserId`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%Y-%m-%d %T') 
SEPARATOR ';'),';',10),';',-1) 10th_Transaction_date FROM `Transactions`
GROUP BY `UserId`;
```

You can see this **[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebaeb7/3)** on how to get the nth record per group in mysql.

Helpful sources:

[Introduction to MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

**NB:** `10th_Transaction_date` is a string not a date.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! But I figure a way out to avoid string manipulation.

Comment: Then that's another solution @XuShen. If my answer is correct then vote it up!